# Load data from json file to bootstrap tables' detailed view section

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to JavaScript and JQuery so please be as clear as possible. I want to change the content of detail view so when I click the "+" button i want it to load another json file that is different from the json file I use for filling the table.

Right now, the detailed view displays id, name, and price values. I want to use a seperate json file that will display the card value.

http://www.iskencecorbasi.com/site/decks.php --- This is the website
https://jsbin.com/milajikoqi/edit?html,output --- This is the code

I believe this part needs a change like "import this json file" before $.each function starts, but not very sure though.

```
    function detailFormatter(index, row) {
      var html = [];
      $.each(row, function (key, value) {
      html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>');
    });
    return html.join('');
    }
```

I want to use json file looks like this:

```
   [
      {
         "card"  : "x"
      },
      {
         "card"  : "y"
      },
      {
         "card"  : "z"
      }
   ]
```

So when user clicks "+" button to see details s/he will see corresponding card values.

Comment: What is the question? As you have tagged `ajax`, I assume you are familiar with that. `detailFormatter` looks fine too.

Comment: I want to call data from another json file to replace current id: 0

name: Item 0

price: $0 structure and just display something like card: "shadow mage".

Comment: Make http request using ``ajax` and on `success` callback function, update the DOM.

Comment: I am not familiar with ajax. I added the tag because I thought it was relevant, just a hunch.

Comment: Unable to guess so may things on my own. Kindly refer this any update your question accordingly => http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask